# Изменение размеров ячеек или отключение автоподгона размеров с помощью Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel

Использую библиотеку `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` для работы с *.xls файлом на C#. После записи информации в ячейки размеры таблицы искажаются. Первое что приходит в голову - отключить автоподгон размеров или же установить свои размеры для всего листа/документа после его редактирования. Как же это сделать?

Comment: Что-то у вас заголовок с вопросом не сходится.

Comment: Упс. Система сохранила заголовок предыдущего вопроса :/ Спасибо за правку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас возникает вопрос "Как пролезть в неведомое что-то через дебри API Офиса", то самый простой подход — это запустить офисное приложение, начать запись VB макроса, проделать нужное вам действие и посмотреть сгенерированный код. Переписаать его на ваш любимый язык программирования не должно составить труда.